# 2 class instances, 1 line

Tags: php, oop, class

If I have two PHP classes `Rappers` and `Rockers`, is this the best way to create an instance of both?

```
$musicians = new Rappers() && new Rockers();
```

**Update:** More specific as to how I wanted to use this is to instantiate another class along with the [Hybrid framework](http://themehybrid.com/hybrid-core) which is wrapped entirely in a class called `Hybrid`. This line would be inside a WordPress theme's `functions.php` file:

```
$theme = new Hybrid() && new Response();
```

Comment: you can dismiss those `()`, not needed in PHP since you're not passing arguments to constructors

Comment: Is this the best way? Umm... no. :) What relation are Rappers and Rockers supposed to have? Do you want two separate objects, or one object that [shares the properties of both?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rap_rock)

Comment: What do you mean by *"an instance of both"* ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What you have will assign `true` to `$musicians` if the classes exist. Why not do `new Rappers; new Rockers;` if you just want to instantiate the objects without assigning them to a variable?

Comment: Are you aware that `$musicians` will be a boolean rather than an instance of either `Rappers()` or `Rockers()`?

Comment: @Marek Sebera Good call about the parens.

Comment: @Pekka I just updated the question to be more specific.

Comment: @ryanve Regarding your update is `Response` a subclass of `Hybrid`? If it is and you want to call the constructor of `Hybrit` (parent class) when you instantiate `Response` (subclass), then inside the constructor of the `Response` you do `parent::__construct();`.

Comment: @Shef No it's not. I considered using `extends` but opted not to so that `Response` could be used outside of `Hybrid` too.

Comment: @ryanve So, you want to have a `Hybrid` object, which you can instantiate with `$hybrid = new Hybrid;` and a `Response` object which you can instantiate with `$response = new Response;`? If you want it to be in one statement you can do `($hybrid = new Hybrid) && ($response = new Response);`, but I don't see any reason for it to be in one statement.

Comment: @ryanve The second one will work(i.e. it will instantiate the objects), but it will assign boolean value to the variable though.

Comment: Now as the answer is given, I must admit that this is not a real question. You should directly ask and make your motivation visible.

Comment: @hakre I was trying to simplify the problem and make it more general.

Comment: @ryanve: Yeah and so manny users had no clue what you asked for ;) Just saying, it's better to ask directly so the question makes more sense. Always think about those who need to answer your question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way would be:

```
$rappers = new Rappers;
$rockers = new Rockers;
```

You can't assign multiple class instances to a single variable it just doesn't make sense

Comment: Thanks // I was surprised when the other way worked so I was trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 3):

```
$musicians = array(new Rappers(), new Rockers());
```

or

```
$rappers = new Rappers();
$rockers = new Rockers();
```

Comment: `$musicians = array(new Rappers(), new Rockers());`...full marks for language mixing :-)

Comment: `array` is a language construct, not a class in PHP. So you can't do `new array()`

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in PHP, as it doesn't support multiple inheritance.  If you're talking about a *collection* of both, you can simply add objects of both classes to an array.  PHP is not a strictly typed language.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if one line code is what you want

```
  list($rappers,$rockers) = array(new Rappers(),new Rockers());
```

or

```
  $mussicians = array(new Rappers(),new Rockers());
  list($rappers,$rockers) = $mussicians;
```

Comment: The beauty of complication. I love this "one-liner" `$rappers = new Rappers; $rockers = new Rockers;` more.

Comment: @shef thats two statements . Beauty is in one statement :)

Comment: No it ain't two statements `($rappers = new Rappers) && ($rockers = new Rockers);`. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on one of your class:

`class Rappers extends Rockers`

then

`$musicians = new Rappers();`

I hope this answer helps